SynchronousOnlyOperation Error in Django Class Based Views
I am making a Django app, but I can't use async views, I installed uvicorn and asgi, but I get this error:

SynchronousOnlyOperation at /chatbot/chat/
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL), name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(never_cache, name='dispatch')
class ChatView(View):

    async def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method return our chatbot view
        """
        
        response = await sync_to_async(render)(request, 'chatbot/chat.html')
        return response


I don't think render needed to be wrapped around sync_to_async if get is an async def function, have you tried using response = render(request, 'chatbot/chat.html') ?

Post the whole traceback, not only the error message.
